# Service (OS X) won't start automatically on demand, says my OS version is too old

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-lion, osx-mountain-lion, deployment-target

I have a text-inserting OS X Service ([created by Mark Aufflick](https://github.com/aufflick/BOFH-Excuse-Service) and [I've been hacking on it](https://github.com/boredzo/BOFH-Excuse-Service)) that's giving me an odd problem.

The service is a .service application, installed in ~/Library/Services. pbs has been duly run to rehash the services list.

The problem is, if I choose the service while it isn't already running, I get this error message:

[image: “The ‘BOFH Excuse Server’ service could not be used because the ‘(null)’ application requires a newer version of Mac OS X.” “Try using an older version of ‘(null),’ or upgrade to a newer version of Mac OS X.”]

I'm on 10.7.5. Mark's original version required 10.8, but I changed the deployment target to 10.7, cleaned, and built, and the only build of this service on my system is built with the 10.7 setting (which the Info.plist in the project also uses as the value of `LSMinimumSystemVersion`, so I can see it there).

If I launch the service manually, from the Finder, I don't get this problem. The service launches and runs and I can then invoke it from other applications.

Aside from the possibilities of the salesman having driven over the CPU board, the computer room being moved and our systems being down for the weekend, or the system having consumed all the paper for paging, what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's not approved by the FCC?

Comment: That, or Borg nanites have infested the service.